# Error: Base table or view not found (Laravel 5.5)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Este es el error:

`"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'codearte_site.posts' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from`posts`)"`

> Me pasa con todos los proyectos que tengo en laravel en la pc, siempre el mismo eror `'codearte_site.<table_name>'`

archivo web.php

```
Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('post')->group(function () {
        Route::get('list', 'PostController@list');
    });
});
```

archivo PostController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function list(){
        return response()->json( Post::paginate(10) );
    }
}
```

archivo Post.php

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'content', 'slug'];
}
```

archivo .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=codeartes
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

No sé donde más revisar, ya apagué el MySql y lo encendí.. no se que hacer.

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama tu tabla en la bd ? , puede asignar ese nombre a la propiedad `$table` de su modelo `Post` , `protected $table = 'nombretabla';`

Comment: Abrí el archivo `database.php` (dentro de la carpeta `config`) y fijate que valor tiene la clave `prefix` dentro del array `mysql`.

Comment: Podrías por favor publicar también el archivo de migración para esta tabla?... Lo otro en el archivo de basededatos aparece este nombre: codeartes. pero en el error aparece este nombre codearte_site. Será que falta cambiar el nombre de la base de datos?

Comment: Lo que no veo es donde llamas a la vista para cargar poder cargar el JSON de la ruta api/post/list. Te recomiendo que pruebes haciendo una consulta desde tinker para descartar problemas con la configuracion, modelo y migracion de tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que no hayas ejecutado las migraciones, de ser asi en tu terminal teclea.

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Al ver el error de la consola se puede leer que, la tabla no existe, esto puede deberse a que aun no has hecho la migración

- Esto lo podemos solucionar con este comando:

  `php artisan migrate:refresh`

con refresh lo que estas haciendo es un rollback (eliminando las tablas) y crearlas nuevamente.

- la segunda opcion es crear tu bd, migracion y controlladores con el siguiente comando:

  `php artisan make:model nameModel -mc`

con ello evitas que te equivoques menos en los nombres.